# phpstorm + TortiseSVN + subversion/visualsvn?

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

I am using PhpStorm and Dreamweaver for my PHP projects, but now we are going to start on a project on which 6-8 persons will be working together.

I want to know which is better Subversion or VisualSVN?

Is it possible to to use VisualSVN with PhpStorm?

Setup is like everyone have there own pc, and one fileserver.

However that server is also being used by .NET team, which they have installed the Team Foundation Server.

Now I also want to use that same server with TortiseSVN and Subversion or VisualSVN anything that works better with PhpStorm and Dreamweaver.

Need all of you developers, Guidance.

**Which approach is better? and should be followed.**

Also keeping in mind, I don't want to use Subversion installed on a local PC, every PC is been given only 80GB space which includes, softwares, drivers windows etc.
Only want to setup the main centeral Subversion server, but the secure one.

Comment: The question *"which is better Subversion or VisualSVN"* is a bit odd.

Comment: @bahrep
Sorry my fault,
I was new to it and was struggling to know what actually is this.
Now its becoming more clear to me.
At that time i was referring this as to subversion
http://subversion.apache.org/
LOL. But Now i am using VisualSVN Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [VisualSVN Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VisualSVN_Server) is an [Apache Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/) server package for Windows.
- You can access VisualSVN Server with PhpStorm or Dreamweaver. No issues with that.
- You can install VisualSVN Server on a server machine (obviously).

Comment: Sir, i have Chosen VisualSVN and i installed and did the setup on the windows 2008 Server.
i accessed it on the other PC, it is working great.

But i want to setup the PHPStorm on client PC to connect to that server with VisualSVN.
That Feature is available on the dreamweaver easily for manage site,
But i can't find it over the PHPStorm

Comment: @SyedHaiderHassan for PhpStorm please consider the help article at http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/using-subversion-integration.html